# Textured quad not rendering

Tags: graphics, 2d, rendering, directx-11

Okay, I'm trying to render an image in 2D using DirectX 11. I understand that it needs to be handled like a 3D operation and rendered as a textured quad. The problem is that nothing is rendering and I can't figure out how to track down the problem.

I've got [my project on GitLab](https://gitlab.com/black-plain-games/lawnmower/tree/master/source) and will post snippets here, but feel free to check out the repo so you can get the full picture. Everything I've done is based on the popular [rastertek tutorials](http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut11.html).

The vertex/pixel shader I'm using works for 3D triangles I've rendered.

Vertex Shader:

```
cbuffer MatrixBuffer
{
    matrix World;
    matrix View;
    matrix Projection;
};

struct VertexInputType
{
    float4 Position : POSITION;
    float2 TextureCoordinate : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct PixelInputType
{
    float4 Position : SV_POSITION;
    float2 TextureCoordinate : TEXCOORD0;
};

PixelInputType main(VertexInputType input)
{
    PixelInputType output;

    input.Position.w = 1.0f;

    output.Position = mul(input.Position, World);
    output.Position = mul(output.Position, View);
    output.Position = mul(output.Position, Projection);

    output.Position.z = 0.0f;

    output.TextureCoordinate = input.TextureCoordinate;

    return output;
}
```

Pixel Shader

```
Texture2D Texture;

SamplerState SampleType;

struct PixelInputType
{
    float4 Position : SV_POSITION;
    float2 TextureCoordinate: TEXCOORD0;
};

float4 main(PixelInputType input) : SV_TARGET
{
    return Texture.Sample(SampleType, input.TextureCoordinate);
}
```

The only difference between the 3D and 2D use of this shader is that the projection matrix is set to the orthographic matrix when I render in 2D. Here's the vertices I'm using:

```cs
// calculate position
vertices[0].Position = DirectX::XMFLOAT3(_positionX, _positionY, 0);
vertices[1].Position = DirectX::XMFLOAT3(_positionX + _width, _positionY, 0);
vertices[2].Position = DirectX::XMFLOAT3(_positionX, _positionY + _height, 0);
vertices[3].Position = DirectX::XMFLOAT3(_positionX + _width, _positionY + _height, 0);

// calculate texture
vertices[0].TextureCoordinate = DirectX::XMFLOAT2(0, 0);
vertices[1].TextureCoordinate = DirectX::XMFLOAT2(1, 0);
vertices[2].TextureCoordinate = DirectX::XMFLOAT2(0, 1);
vertices[3].TextureCoordinate = DirectX::XMFLOAT2(1, 1);
```

And here's the indices I'm passing in:

```cs
auto indices = new long[6]
{
    0, 3, 2,
    0, 1, 3
};
```

This is the render call for my sprite class:

```cs
unsigned int stride = sizeof(TexturedVertex);
unsigned int offset = 0;

context->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &_vertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);

context->IASetIndexBuffer(_indexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);

context->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

context->DrawIndexed(6, 0, 0);
```

I don't want to just make walls of code here, so I'll leave out some other key details (like how the shaders are applied) but again feel free to dig around on GitLab to see what I've omitted.

I believe my winding order is correct and because I'm drawing an indexed primitive I think I'm fine having 4 vertices for a quad (instead of the 6 that the tutorial suggests).

I've tried using Visual Studio 2019's graphics debugging tools, which are really cool but sort of too much for me to digest right now. I see that I can dig into each DX object and see what properties are set to but there's nothing standing out to me as the problem. I was thinking if I could debug the shaders I might be able to see the problem but the instructions in VS for shader debugging aren't clear/correct; it tells me to turn on an option I can't find in the menu.

I've tried using PIX and it crashes with the following output:

```
 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097273: CREATE_DEPTHSTENCILSTATE]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11RasterizerState: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x0934BE0C, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097276: CREATE_RASTERIZERSTATE]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Sampler: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x00200F0C, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097267: CREATE_SAMPLER]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Query: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x08F7D51C, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097279: CREATE_QUERY]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Query: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x08F7ED8C, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097279: CREATE_QUERY]
D3D11 INFO: Destroy ID3D11Query: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x08F7ED8C [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097281: DESTROY_QUERY]
D3D11 INFO: Destroy ID3D11Query: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x08F7D51C [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097281: DESTROY_QUERY]
D3D11 INFO: Destroy ID3D11RasterizerState: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x0934BE0C [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097278: DESTROY_RASTERIZERSTATE]
D3D11 INFO: Destroy ID3D11DepthStencilState: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x08D8FDB4 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097275: DESTROY_DEPTHSTENCILSTATE]
D3D11 INFO: Destroy ID3D11BlendState: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x086DEB7C [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097272: DESTROY_BLENDSTATE]
D3D11 INFO: Destroy ID3D11Sampler: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x00200F0C [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097269: DESTROY_SAMPLER]
D3D11 INFO: Destroy ID3D11Context: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x09260050 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097227: DESTROY_CONTEXT]
D3D11 INFO: Destroy ID3DDeviceContextState: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x093293C0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #3145749: DESTROY_DEVICECONTEXTSTATE]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Context: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x09260050, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097225: CREATE_CONTEXT]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3DDeviceContextState: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x09328CC8, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #3145735: CREATE_DEVICECONTEXTSTATE]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11BlendState: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x08E4002C, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097270: CREATE_BLENDSTATE]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11DepthStencilState: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x0933CEC4, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097273: CREATE_DEPTHSTENCILSTATE]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11RasterizerState: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x002FA694, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097276: CREATE_RASTERIZERSTATE]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Sampler: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x08E5B784, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097267: CREATE_SAMPLER]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Query: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x094EC04C, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097279: CREATE_QUERY]
D3D11 INFO: Destroy ID3D11Query: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x094EC04C [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097281: DESTROY_QUERY]
D3D11 INFO: Destroy ID3D11RasterizerState: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x002FA694 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097278: DESTROY_RASTERIZERSTATE]
D3D11 INFO: Destroy ID3D11DepthStencilState: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x0933CEC4 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097275: DESTROY_DEPTHSTENCILSTATE]
D3D11 INFO: Destroy ID3D11BlendState: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x08E4002C [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097272: DESTROY_BLENDSTATE]
D3D11 INFO: Destroy ID3D11Sampler: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x08E5B784 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097269: DESTROY_SAMPLER]
D3D11 INFO: Destroy ID3D11Context: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x09260050 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097227: DESTROY_CONTEXT]
D3D11 INFO: Destroy ID3DDeviceContextState: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x09328CC8 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #3145749: DESTROY_DEVICECONTEXTSTATE]
Frame 000001 ............PRE: AddObject(DXGI Factory, 0x070C4F90, 0x086E70B0)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <TRUE> AddObject(DXGI Factory, 0x070C4F90, 0x086E70B0)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK> CreateDXGIFactory(IID_IDXGIFactory, 0x005EF4D8)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x070c4f90>IDXGIFactory::EnumAdapters(0, 0x005EF4C0)
Frame 000001 ............PRE: AddObject(DXGI Adapter, 0x07085DB0, 0x0926B2E8)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <TRUE> AddObject(DXGI Adapter, 0x07085DB0, 0x0926B2E8)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x070c4f90> IDXGIFactory::EnumAdapters(0, 0x005EF4C0)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x07085db0>IDXGIAdapter::EnumOutputs(0, 0x005EF4B4)
Frame 000001 ............PRE: AddObject(DXGI Output, 0x07085E08, 0x086E82F8)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <TRUE> AddObject(DXGI Output, 0x07085E08, 0x086E82F8)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x07085db0> IDXGIAdapter::EnumOutputs(0, 0x005EF4B4)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x07085e08>IDXGIOutput::GetDisplayModeList(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, 1, 0x005EF4A8, NULL)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x07085e08> IDXGIOutput::GetDisplayModeList(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, 1, 0x005EF4A8, NULL)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x07085e08>IDXGIOutput::GetDisplayModeList(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, 1, 0x005EF490, 0x08E48768)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x07085e08> IDXGIOutput::GetDisplayModeList(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, 1, 0x005EF490, 0x08E48768)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x07085e08>IDXGIOutput::Release()
Frame 000001 ............PRE: RemoveObject(DXGI Output, 0x07085E08, 0x086E82F8)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <> RemoveObject(DXGI Output, 0x07085E08, 0x086E82F8)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <0><this=0x07085e08> IDXGIOutput::Release()
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x07085db0>IDXGIAdapter::Release()
Frame 000001 ............PRE: RemoveObject(DXGI Adapter, 0x07085DB0, 0x0926B2E8)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <> RemoveObject(DXGI Adapter, 0x07085DB0, 0x0926B2E8)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <0><this=0x07085db0> IDXGIAdapter::Release()
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x070c4f90>IDXGIFactory::Release()
Frame 000001 ............PRE: RemoveObject(DXGI Factory, 0x070C4F90, 0x086E70B0)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <> RemoveObject(DXGI Factory, 0x070C4F90, 0x086E70B0)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <0><this=0x070c4f90> IDXGIFactory::Release()
Frame 000001 ........PRE: D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, 2, 0x005EF3D0, 2, 7, 0x005EF3E0, 0x0023A360, 0x0023A364, NULL, 0x0023A368)
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Context: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x09260050, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097225: CREATE_CONTEXT]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3DDeviceContextState: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x09328CC8, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #3145735: CREATE_DEVICECONTEXTSTATE]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11BlendState: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x093B486C, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097270: CREATE_BLENDSTATE]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11DepthStencilState: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x09352A94, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097273: CREATE_DEPTHSTENCILSTATE]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11RasterizerState: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x08E404DC, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097276: CREATE_RASTERIZERSTATE]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Sampler: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x08D8FE24, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097267: CREATE_SAMPLER]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Query: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x092F52F4, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097279: CREATE_QUERY]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Texture2D: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x095F47C4, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097234: CREATE_TEXTURE2D]
Frame 000001 ............PRE: AddObject(D3D11 Device, 0x07085FD0, 0x094E9EB4)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <TRUE> AddObject(D3D11 Device, 0x07085FD0, 0x094E9EB4)
Frame 000001 ............PRE: AddObject(DXGI Factory, 0x070C4F90, 0x086E70B0)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <TRUE> AddObject(DXGI Factory, 0x070C4F90, 0x086E70B0)
Frame 000001 ............PRE: AddObject(DXGI Adapter, 0x07086030, 0x0926B2E8)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <TRUE> AddObject(DXGI Adapter, 0x07086030, 0x0926B2E8)
Frame 000001 ............PRE: AddObject(DXGI Device, 0x07086088, 0x094E9EB0)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <TRUE> AddObject(DXGI Device, 0x07086088, 0x094E9EB0)
Frame 000001 ............PRE: AddObject(DXGI Swap Chain, 0x070860E8, 0x0929F848)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <TRUE> AddObject(DXGI Swap Chain, 0x070860E8, 0x0929F848)
Frame 000001 ............PRE: AddObject(DXGI Surface, 0x07086180, 0x095F48DC)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <TRUE> AddObject(DXGI Surface, 0x07086180, 0x095F48DC)
Frame 000001 ............PRE: AddObject(D3D10 Texture2D, 0x070861E0, 0x095F487C)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <TRUE> AddObject(D3D10 Texture2D, 0x070861E0, 0x095F487C)
Frame 000001 ............PRE: AddObject(D3D11 Device Context, 0x070C4FE8, 0x09260050)
Frame 000001 ............POST: <TRUE> AddObject(D3D11 Device Context, 0x070C4FE8, 0x09260050)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK> D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, 2, 0x005EF3D0, 2, 7, 0x005EF3E0, 0x0023A360, 0x0023A364, NULL, 0x0023A368)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x07085fd0>ID3D11Device::QueryInterface({0x79cf2233, 0x7536, 0x4948, 0x9d, 0x36, 0x1e, 0x46, 0x92, 0xdc, 0x57, 0x60}, 0x005EF3C4)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x07085fd0> ID3D11Device::QueryInterface({0x79cf2233, 0x7536, 0x4948, 0x9d, 0x36, 0x1e, 0x46, 0x92, 0xdc, 0x57, 0x60}, 0x005EF3C4)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x07085fd0>ID3D11Device::QueryInterface({0x6543dbb6, 0x1b48, 0x42f5, 0xab, 0x82, 0xe9, 0x7e, 0xc7, 0x43, 0x26, 0xf6}, 0x005EF3B8)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x07085fd0> ID3D11Device::QueryInterface({0x6543dbb6, 0x1b48, 0x42f5, 0xab, 0x82, 0xe9, 0x7e, 0xc7, 0x43, 0x26, 0xf6}, 0x005EF3B8)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x070860e8>IDXGISwapChain::GetBuffer(0, IID_ID3D11Texture2D, 0x005EF3AC)
Frame 000001 ........POST: <S_OK><this=0x070860e8> IDXGISwapChain::GetBuffer(0, IID_ID3D11Texture2D, 0x005EF3AC)
Frame 000001 ........PRE: <this=0x07085fd0>ID3D11Device::CreateRenderTargetView(0x070861E0, NULL, 0x0023A36C)
D3D11 CORRUPTION: ID3D11Device::CreateRenderTargetView: First parameter is corrupt! [ MISCELLANEOUS CORRUPTION #13: CORRUPTED_PARAMETER1]
D3D11: **BREAK** enabled for the previous message, which was: [ CORRUPTION MISCELLANEOUS #13: CORRUPTED_PARAMETER1 ]
An unhandled exception occurred.
```

This seems to be pointing to this bit of code:

```cs
ID3D11Texture2D* backBufferPtr = nullptr;

result = _swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)(&backBufferPtr));

FailFast(result);

// this line seems to be the "error"
result = _device->CreateRenderTargetView(backBufferPtr, nullptr, &_renderTargetView);
```

I don't experience this exception when debugging my code from Visual Studio.

I'm looking for better ways to debug my DirectX 11 application so I can solve these problems myself in the future. I'd also like to figure out what I'm doing wrong with PIX (it's probably some assumption my app is making that is breaking when run from PIX). And most importantly I'd like to figure out what I'm doing wrong when trying to render this 2D quad.

Let me know if you need more information to help. Thank you!

Edit:
I've also uploaded the XML output from the frame analysis from VS, which I think the only key piece of insight this shows is the calls made to DX this frame. [Check it out here](https://pastebin.com/9aH9D8cb).

Edit:
I'm using PIX version 9.29.1962.0000 (64-bit) June 2010. I'm running Windows 10 Build 17134. I've just realized this version of PIX probably predates DX11 so I'm checking out the latest version from Microsoft right now. I'll update with results.

Comment: Debugging such problems can be very tricky, indeed. In the Visual Studio Graphics Debugger, you should be able to select a draw call and see the results of the individual stages (Vertex Shader, PS), even without line-by-line shader debugging. Maybe this gives you an idea. You should also be able to see the bound buffers and data declarations - maybe there is something wrong with those. Finally, if you are on an NVIDIA GPU, you might have more luck with shader debugging with [Nsight](https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition).

Comment: Which version of "PIX" are you using? The one from the legacy DirectX SDK? Which OS are you using?